# Is it possible to serve an ASPX page without it setting a cookie on your browser?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, cookieless, iis-7.5

we're in the process of trying to speed up the performance of our website by serving [static content from a cookieless domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060775/stopping-cookies-being-set-from-a-domain-aka-cookieless-domain-to-increase-si). That seems to be going well, but I have a new question:

I know that it's "static content" that we're talking about when serving it from a cookieless domain, but we also have static content being served by ASPX pages, specifically images. For example:

```
domain.com/resizeImages.aspx?src=images/image123.jpg&width=400&height=400
```

(Note: The above would be in an `<img>` tag, obviously.)

Pretty standard stuff, and although it's being served by managed code, it's still a static image.

**So my question is:** How can I serve the *resizeImages.aspx* image without ASP.NET setting a cookie on my browser? (At present it sets an ASPXANONYMOUS cookie.)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why use a whole aspx page when you can write a handler that won't need to go through a full page life-cycle?  If you're working on speeding up performance that would probably help more than cookies.

Comment: This is possibly a very good question. I have absolutely no idea as to its answer. I didn't even know it would be possible to resize and serve and image through a handler... I'm a bit of a newb, I'm afraid.

Comment: Our developer has put together an .ashx page instead. Will that work?

Comment: It worked! Thanks for your help. No need to worry about cookies now, either. We're reduced them elsewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things cookies are used for is to keep track of your session token, you could try [disabling state](http://dotnettipoftheday.org/tips/page-enabledsessionstate.aspx) for that page and see if it makes the cookie go away *(though a custom handler would probably be a better solution)*.