# How to setup an ASP.Net/IIS Web Application to serve static content from a cookieless domain

Tags: asp.net, performance, web-applications, static-content, cookieless

In my quest to get the best performance for an ASP.Net/IIS based web application, I would like to have static content be served up from a cookieless domain as suggested by Google.

I have followed this discussion and understand how it would work. [Stopping cookies being set from a domain (aka "cookieless domain") to increase site performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060775/stopping-cookies-being-set-from-a-domain-aka-cookieless-domain-to-increase-s)

What I fail to understand is how to have the image/js/css files' src point to the new domain name instead of the one resolved by the browser when served up from the original web application.

Here is what I mean -

Original Web Application in IIS at myapp.mydomain.com
Cookieless Web Application in IIS at static.mydomain.com
img tag in a web page is served to the browser from the original Web Application as src="Images/someimage.jpg" which the browser automatically resolves to myapp.mydomain.com/Images/someimage.jpg

The problem for which I am looking for a simple and a smart solution -

Across the application, how do I get the img and asp:image to serve absolute URLs instead of the relative URLs. i.e. have the img tag get the absolute URL as src="//static.mydomain.com/image/someimage.jpg"

PS: I have also referred to [How do I setup IIS with a cookieless domain to improve performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956458/how-do-i-setup-iis-with-a-cookieless-domain-to-improve-performance) and lot of similar contents, but all of these are tell you **what** is to be done, but not the **how** to implement at the ground level.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide the fully qualified url:

```
src="//static.mydomain.com/image/someimage.jpg"
```

or

```
src="http://static.mydomain.com/image/someimage.jpg"
```

I don't see any other way around it.

Comment: This means that if I am trying to optimize an existing application (a large one) a huge number of URLs will have to be changed! I am sure there must be a better way out - some configuration at the application level.